# Are there any tools for posting to Orkut and Facebook together?

Tags: facebook, google-workspace, orkut

I have accounts in both social networking sites Facebook and Orkut. The problem is that if I want to post I have to do it twice because the friends at both sites are mutually exclusive.

I also use Google Buzz and Twitter, but as Google Buzz is linking Tweets from my Twitter account I only have to post once.

So is there any similar way to do post at one place but appear it in Facebook and Orkut?

Comment: Both Buzz and Orkut are dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posting to various stuff like Facebook, Buzz and Twitter, the application "TweetDeck" (http://www.tweetdeck.com/) has worked pretty well for me, and was quite quick to incorporate Buzz, when that was released - and can also counter for the big delay caused when Buzz pulls your tweets from Twitter (see: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2772/why-arent-my-tweets-making-it-to-google-buzz/2882#2882).

I'm not sure how long exactly Orkut has been out, but if the option gets there, I'm quite sure TweetDeck will be quick to incorporate it, whenever/if the option arises.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Orkut is so closed social networking website. In past, I was using a site: orkutfeeds.com - to extract my Orkut posts / scrap entries as RSS feed. I am not sure if this works fine now. Try it - get RSS feeds of Orkut entries & then use any RSS application to post these entries to Facebook profile, used for posting normal blog feeds.